# SQL Server Testing against JSON Column

Tags: json, sql-server

I have the following SQL that works fine as far as it goes:

```
SELECT PlacementId, pp.*
        FROM Placement AS p
        CROSS APPLY OpenJson(p.PlacementDetails)
        WITH(
        PlacementDetails nvarchar(max) '$.PlacementDetails' AS JSON,
        UserName nvarchar(max) '$.UserName',
        LeadBroker nvarchar(max) '$.LeadBroker',
        PocBroker nvarchar(max) '$.PocBroker',
        AssignedTo nvarchar(max) '$.AssignedTo',
        RenewalDate nvarchar(max) '$.RenewalDate',
        StatusId      int '$.StatusId',
        CreatedAt nvarchar(max) '$.CreatedAt',
        SavedBy nvarchar(max) '$.SavedBy',
        ClientName nvarchar(max) '$.ClientName',
        RegionName nvarchar(max) '$.RegionName',
        SavedAt nvarchar(max) '$.SavedAt',
        DueDate nvarchar(max) '$.DueDate',
        Progress nvarchar(max) '$.Progress',
        Premium nvarchar(max) '$.Premium',
        Comments nvarchar(max) '$.Comments',
        Deleted bit '$.Deleted',
        IsLegacyData bit '$.IsLegacyData'
        ) as pp
        where pp.Deleted=0
```

Now I want to add an additional filter against an item on placement details.
If I additionally add the following to the end of my select statement :

```
and (json_value([pp.PlacementDetails],'$PlacementDetails[0].Questions[5].Answer')) = 'TEMCSER-01'
```

SQL returns invalid column name pp.PlacementDetails. How should I adjust the above so that I can filter on my JSON value?

Comment: Will it be '$.PlacementDetails...' instead of '$PlacementDetails' ?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried `p` and I just tried it on it's own with no alias and still the same error

Comment: @EralperI tried your suggestion and still received the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shold seperate table alias and column name

```
  and (json_value(pp.[PlacementDetails],'$.PlacementDetails[0].Questions[5].Answer')) = 'TEMCSER-01'
```